# Relational DB schema design - How to model 1-to-1 mapping right from an entity's set of fields

Tags: mysql, orm, graphql, entity-attribute-value, prisma

I am working on a `MySQL` (via Prisma datamodel) schema for a `Customer` entity in an e-commerce context. As the number of fields have exploded (on including say, engagement tracking) I have two possible designs here:

```
type Customer {
  email: String! @unique
  name: String
  birthDate: DateTime
  addresses: [Address!]!
  ...
  productsVisited: [Product!]!
  productsShared: [Product!]!
  productsSearched: [Product!]!
  ...
}
```

**That, or should fields conveying info together should be carved out into their own table, and joined to the previous one by a 1-to-1 relation:**

```
 type Customer {
  profile: CustomerProfile! @relation(name: "CustomerProfile", onDelete: CASCADE)
  addresses: [Address!]!
  ...
  productEngagements: ProductEngagement! @relation(name: "CustomerProductEngagements", onDelete: CASCADE)
  ...
}

type CustomerProfile {
  customer: Customer! @relation(name: "CustomerProfile", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  email: String! @unique
  name: String
  birthDate: DateTime
}

type ProductEngagement {
  customer: Customer! @relation(name: "CustomerProductEngagements", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  productsVisited: [Product!]!
  productsShared: [Product!]!
  productsSearched: [Product!]!
}
```

**QUESTIONS:**

> 1. What is the right way of thinking design here? I am currently driven by my ER diagrams, and intuition. Do I get or lose any execution or flexibility advantage with making a table thin w.r.t. number of columns?
> 2. In the second method, do queries have to do extra work for table joins?

**Abstract Question:**

> Is a method definitely better than the other, given evolving schema, or performance criteria? Or, is this just a matter of taste here?

Comment: It is _usually_ bad design to have two database tables in a 1:1 relationship.  If you provide `CREATE TABLEs`, I may have more specific comments from a database point of view.  (Or I may agree with doing 1:1.)

Comment: Hi @Rick, I understand your point, and I have come to the same conclusion that abstraction of grouping columns together is better to be done at application server level, and not at the database. I request you to kindly provide your design perspective as a purely RDBMS focussed technical answer, elaborating on "why the choice X", so that I could learn the logic, and accept it. (Also, I don't have CREATE TABLEs since I am using Prisma ORM API). Thanks a lot; looking forward to your answer!

Comment: If you are moving toward an Entity-Attribute-Value schema pattern, I recommend you look at the EAV tag; there are strong reasons to avoid it.

Comment: @RickJames I had gone through EAV post warnings, an still chosen to go with it in my Product-Variant relationship (only). [People were lighter on it in this context :) ]

Comment: There are probably over a hundred 3rd-party packages between the user an MySQL.  I can't begin to keep up with them.  Perhaps I have seen graphql once, but prisma never.  I spend a lot of time on this forum helping users learn MySQL because their chosen package fails to sufficiently isolate them from MySQL.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a RDBMS, there is rarely any good reason for splitting a table into two tables in a 1:1 relationship.  To `JOIN` them back together in a `SELECT` is certainly possible, but adds some overhead, code complexity, and is a slight performance hit.

That being said, I have (rarely) encountered a cases where such a "vertical partitioning" is beneficial.

- There are "too many" columns in the one table, and splitting avoids hitting some database limit...  (This situation is likely to be better handled by some other solution.)
- Some of the columns are both bulky and rarely used...  By moving them into a separate table, the `JOIN` is usually avoided, and the potential performance hit for "bulky" is usually avoided.
- You need to add some columns to a huge table, but the `ALTER TABLE` command is so costly (think, downtime) that you are desperate to find a way to avoid it...  Such a separate table is quick, easy, etc.  (But, of course, suffers from the inconvenience, etc, of needing the `JOIN`.)
- You have a set of columns that are rarely present in the table...  Before splitting them out, you intended to populate the columns with `NULLs` (a valid thing to do).  But after splitting them out, you simply don't have a row in the other table.  Then you use a `LEFT JOIN`, thereby reconstructing the `NULLs` out of thin air.

Comment: Admittedly, as I am in the starting phases, I haven't encountered these extreme cases, but I think the second one really resonates with my intuition. This is a list to keep! Thanks Rick, I hope I will get as far to ask question on this list :)

Comment: I saw the need for the second item many years ago with MyISAM.  InnoDB does a pretty good job of "doing that for you".  If a record gets over 8KB, it will automatically and silently move some of the column values into another block.  It is _usually_ a win-win, and you don't need to understand the details, nor try to 'be smarter than it'.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches definitely will work and it indeed somewhat depends on your personal preferences and the API you want to have when working with the data.

With the second approach you've outlined, Prisma will indeed create tables for `CustomerProfile`, `ProductEngagement` and all other types (as a general rule, Prisma maps all the type definitions from your datamodel to their own tables). So, as @rick-james pointed out, there might be overhead in the `JOIN`s that need to be performed when retrieving the data.

> What is the right way of thinking design here? I am currently driven by my ER diagrams.

This generally is a valid approach, since the Prisma datamodel ultimately is mapped to the database. In that sense, it should be fine to think of it in terms of an ER-diagram.

Also note that Prisma will soon support *embeeded types* which allow to define a type in the Prisma datamodel that does not get its own table but where the data is rather stored in a JSON column inside of the table of a non-embedded type. This is currently already supported when using Prisma with MongoDB but not yet with SQL. You can learn more about this topic in [this feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2836).

Comment: Thanks @nburk, I was waiting for your inputs, and it indeed is a detailed answer. I think I will keep such fields in a single type at Prisma level, and will be breaking them as in second case at the application graphql server (Apollo v2) level. Do you approve this design?